# how to save two file from two different html file upload in same function using angularjs and MVC3

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-mvc-3

here is my all code i am trying to upload small image and large image separate but angularjs not let me allow to do this, it only taking one file but not taking other one. plz anyone help with this. thanks in advance.

```
<div ng-app="eventModule" >
<div ng-controller="eventController">
<div>
<span >Thumbnail Image</span>
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectThumbnail(this.files)"  accept="image/*"  />
</div>
<div>
<span >Large Image</span>
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectLargeImage(this.files)" class="LargeImageSubCategory" />
</div>
</div>
<span  data-ng-click="SaveFile()">Submit</span>
</div>

<script>
    var eventModule = angular.module('eventModule', []);
    eventModule.controller('eventController', function ($scope,ArticleService, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.selectThumbnail = function (file) {
            $scope.SelectedThumbnail = file[0];
        }

        $scope.selectLargeImage = function (file) {
            $scope.SelectedLargeImage = file[0];
        }

        $scope.SaveFile = function () {
            $scope.IsFormSubmitted = true;
            $scope.Message = "";
            ArticleService.UploadFile($scope.SelectedThumbnail, $scope.SelectedLargeImage).then(function (d) {
                alert(d.Message);
                ClearForm();
            }, function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
         };
    });
    eventModule.service("ArticleService", function ($http, $q) {
        this.UploadFile = function (Thumbnail, LargeImage, TitleHeading, Topic, SmallDesc, LargeDesc) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("Thumbnail", Thumbnail);
            formData.append("LargeImage", LargeImage);
            // here when i am trying to send two files so controller is not called
            //and function is breaking and alert is comming "File Upload Failed"
            formData.append("TitleHeading", TitleHeading);
            formData.append("Topic", Topic);
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post("/Articles/SaveFiles", formData,
            {
               withCredentials: true,
               headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
               transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).success(function (d) {
               defer.resolve(d);
            }).error(function () {
               defer.reject("File Upload Failed!");
            });
            return defer.promise;
         }
    });
</script>

//And My ArticlesController.cs code is

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveFiles(string TitleHeading, string Topic)
{
string Message, fileName, actualFileName;
Message = fileName = actualFileName = string.Empty;
bool flag = false;
if (Request.Files != null)
{
var file = Request.Files[0];
actualFileName = file.FileName;
fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
int size = file.ContentLength;
try
{
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), fileName));
using (TCDataClassesDataContext dc = new TCDataClassesDataContext())
{
Article insert = new Article();
insert.ArticleId = Guid.NewGuid();
insert.TitleHeading = TitleHeading;
insert.SmallImagePath = fileName;
dc.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
dc.SubmitChanges();
Message = "File uploaded successfully";
flag = true;
}
}
catch (Exception)
{
Message = "File upload failed! Please try again";
}}
return new JsonResult { Data = new { Message = Message, Status = flag } };
}
```

Comment: Does `$scope.SelectedThumbnail` and `$scope.SelectedLargeImage` have the correct values?

Comment: ye both have correct values

Comment: then try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the files to the `formdata`, thus you need to specify the `Thumbnail` and `LargeImage` as parameters of your MVC controller. Please see below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveFiles(
          HttpPostedFileBase thumbnail
        , HttpPostedFileBase largeImage
        , string titleHeading
        , string topic)
    {
        string Message, fileName, actualFileName;
        Message = fileName = actualFileName = string.Empty;
        bool flag = false;

        if (thumbnail != null && thumbnail.ContentLength != 0) 
        {
            SaveFile(thumbnail);
        }

        if (largeImage != null && largeImage.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            SaveFile(largeImage);
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { Message = Message, Status = flag } };
    }

    private void SaveFile(
        HttpPostedFileBase httpFile) 
    {
        var actualFileName = httpFile.FileName;
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(httpFile.FileName);
        int size = httpFile.ContentLength;
        try
        {
            httpFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), fileName));
            using (TCDataClassesDataContext dc = new TCDataClassesDataContext())
            {
                Article insert = new Article();
                insert.ArticleId = Guid.NewGuid();
                insert.TitleHeading = TitleHeading;
                insert.SmallImagePath = fileName;
                dc.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(insert);
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                Message = "File uploaded successfully";
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Message = "File upload failed! Please try again";
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually problem is in client side code by attaching both file function is not calling..server side function is only calling for one file.

Comment: @Nitesh can you see what the actual error being returned is?

Comment: when i am trying to attach this line "formData.append("Thumbnail", Thumbnail);formData.append("LargeImage", LargeImage);" both in client side then function(SaveFiles) is not calling. but when i am sending  "formData.append("Thumbnail", Thumbnail);"  then SaveFiles function is calling..angularjs is not taking both file at same time, its taking only one

Comment: @Nitesh can you see what the error is in chrome network monitor? Or some similar tool?